# vue.js - How to manage vuex state on changing routes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I have routes like this:

- `/forum/abc/user/23/{posts, profile,...}`
- `/forum/cde/user/28/{posts,profile,...}`

In my Vuex Store, I want to have the current `Forum` and `User` objects, so components like `Profile.vue` can access them.

```
state: {
  forum: null,
  user: null,
}
```

When the router enters `/forum/abc/user/23`, `forum` and `user` should be loaded. When the user navigates to `/forum/abc/user/23/posts`, the data doesn't need to be reloaded, but when the user switches to `/forum/def/user/28/posts`, the state needs to be updated.

At the moment, I solved it with nested routes. I have a `Forum.vue` component and a `User.vue` component, which are similar and look like this:

*Forum.vue:*

```
<template>
    <!-- "Key" to signal Vue to rerender the component on param change -->
    <router-view :key="this.$route.path"></router-view>
</template>    
<script>
  import store from "@/store/store.js";   
  export default {
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
      store.dispatch("fetchForum");
    },
    beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
      store.dispatch("fetchForum");
    },  
  }
</script>
```

In my routes, I nest `Forum` and `User`, so both are always included, but they don't render anything. They are just responsible for route changes and triggering the Vuex store update.

```
export default {
    path: "/forum/:forum([a-z]+)/",
    components: {
        default: Forum,
        navigation: Navigation,
    },
    props: true,
    children: [
        {
            path: "",
            name: "ForumHome",
            component: ForumHome,
        },
        {
            path: "/user/:user([0-9]+)/",
            name: "User",
            component: User,
            props: true,
            children: [
              {
                path: "",
                name: "UserHome",
                component: UserHome
              }
            ]
        },
    ]
 }
```

It looks strange to me to define a View Component to listen to Router events to update the state.

Is this the correct way to solve this in Vuex/Vue/VueRouter? Or should this somehow be implemented inside the Vuex store?

Comment: Why your routes are depending on state? I think its not necessary, if you want to retrieve data there are properties or methods `watch`, `computed` or` mounted`.